# How do I install and run Tomcat on port 80 as my only web server? (Rooted Ubuntu box)

Tags: tomcat

**tl;dr** - I have a rooted linux box that I want to run tomcat on as a server (No Apache Web Server) how would you set this up avoiding common security pitfalls?

I've written a Grails App that I want to run on a VPS I rent. The VPS has very little memory and I am using it for the sole purpose of running this application so I don't need the apache web server.

This is my first venture into Server administration and I'm sure to fall into some well known traps.

- Should I use iptables to redirect
  requests from port 80 to 8080?
- Should
  I run tomcat as root or as its own
  user?
- What configuration settings
  would be good for a low memory system
  expecting less than 10 concurrent
  users?

Hopefully an easy one for you! Anyone who could link to a tutorial would be a personal hero destined for great things no doubt.

Gav

Comment: What do you mean by "rooted linux box"? Why did you put "too long; didn't read" on your own question?

Comment: "rooted linux box" - linux box for which I have root access.
tl;dr - I got used to seeing/adding these on reddit, it's for those of you with short attention spans, you can understand what it is that I want to know quickly without reading my life story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run tomcat as the tomcat user.  I don't think you should ever run tomcat as root.  It exposes the potential for a larger security risk than running it as an unprivileged user.

Tomcat's HTTP serving is a bit lacking for some stuff, so i'd always suggest that you have a http server as a frontend.  If you don't want apache, there's always Nginx.  This is especially true if you wanted HTTP Basic or Digest auth.

I'd suggest that you start off with tomcat's default memory settings, then tune them as and when you need to.  With no knowledge of the app's memory profile, it's difficult to give you any hard and fast figures.

If you're using Ubuntu on your vps, you can just apt-get install tomcat6 and it should work out of the "box".  Even on Centos5.4, the tomcat5 package from yum works with minimal config changes.

I seriously advise that you use a lightweight server in front of your tomcat instance though.  This gives you better granular control over security than Tomcat's "Security Manager"

I have Tomcat6 running on a Virtual Machine which runs my hudson CI server, I think i've given it about 256MB of RAM, and it's perfectly happy.

Comment: I ended up using iptables and running tomcat with a dedicated non-root user.

Comment: That's an infinitely better option than running tomcat as root.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you do not have enough space to run a full-fledge web-server in front of Tomcat, you can consider running a reverse-proxy like *pound*. At the very least, it can quickly stop random connections to your server if configured correctly. Just point *pound* to the internal port 8080 that Tomcat listens on.

Comment: pound, nginx, lightttpd, varnish, even Ugh. Squid might do.

Comment: true, there are lots to use. i suggested pound because it is simple to use.