# How do you relay HTTP Port 80 Connections to Tomcat Port 8080?

Tags: centos, tomcat, port-forwarding

I am working with a CentOS VPS and would like to achieve this without running tomcat as root.

Answer (score 1):

you have two options:

- Put an apache or other webserver in front of the tomcat server and pass the requests to the tomcat. [This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/164195/change-tomcat-port-to-80-with-apache) shows how.
- Using iptables redirects.

Nearly the same question is discussed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/127110/how-do-i-install-and-run-tomcat-on-port-80-as-my-only-web-server-rooted-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

for iptables redirect you can do like this :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

For CentOS 7, use this:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=8080 --permanent
sudo reboot
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to reboot to apply firewall changes.  Can you suggest a more appropriate command to do so?

Comment: just leave off the --permanent and it will take effect immediately, however it will not survive reboot. If you want to make it permenant (so it works after reboot) use the --permanent